# Is there any library exporting APIs with different calling conventions?

Tags: python, c, ctypes, calling-convention

Is there any example of a library exporting functions with different calling conventions, e.g. `api_foo()` with `__cdecl` and `api_bar()` with `__stdcall`, both in the same public API namespace?

My questions are ...

- if this is possible in principle
- if it also happens in practice, and in that case when/why you would use it

I'm asking on behalf of a python ctypes wrapper generator, wondering if we need to support this case.

Comment: It is absolutely possible. You could use it in a library that provides bindings for multiple languages that use different calling conventions.

Comment: While it's possible, in practice I think it's more common to have a single C API, along with a wrapper library for use from Python.

Comment: It is possible (I've seen it - in my example it was a *.dll* exporting native *C++* functions (default *stdcall*) and also *PyInit\** (default *cdecl* - making it a *Python* extension module)). Anyway I find that kind of design lame, there should have been 2 separate *.dll*s.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Although possible, I figured we probably don't want to support it for now because stdcall is windows-only, and the mix seems to me to be rare/unusual, so it might not be worth the additional complexity.